# cannot do anything after booting ubuntu 12.04 lts  , problem with resolution

Tags: 12.04, resolution, monitor, frequency

I installed the ubuntu on my PC using a different LCD screen and now when I connect it to the monitor that I want to use, I get a problem with the resolution as soon as the ubuntu boots so cant change the resolution from with in the OS after booting. The screenshot is in the link. Is there any way arroung to solve the problem or I need to re install the Ubuntu with the actual monitor plugged in while installing it.
I get out of frequency error
**HF: 68.7 kHz
VF: 85.0Hz
Operating Frequency
HF:30-54 kHz
VF: 50-120 Hz**
After 30 seconds i get a black screen with the cursor blinking for some time and then the monitor shuts off.

[image: screen shot of the issue]

Comment: Connect to actual moniter and follow http://askubuntu.com/q/153040/35775

Comment: How do I get into terminal. All i can do is get into the GRUB console

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a live usb. Try booting through it.

If you succeed do the following,

1. Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
2. Click `Advanced options`
3. Go to the `GRUB options` tab
4. Tick the `out-of-range` option
5. Apply

If you failed to boot with ubuntu live disk. Prepare a disk for [Boot repair ISO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/). This should do the work.

Comment: A live USB is not necessary. A live CD will do just fine.