# Question about mounting, 'input not supported' error and grub-probe error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, mount

I am trying to install Kubuntu 15.04 from a liveUSB on a hard drive without a prior OS. The machine has a GeForce GTX 980 GPU. The primary problem is that when I boot from the USB and begin the installation process, I eventually see the message `Input Not Supported` floating across a blank screen. I open a terminal, use the default login parameters, and edit the GRUB config file using the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

I find the following line and remove the hash (#):

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

I save the grub config file and try to run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

I am met with the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'
```

I have read the articles here about this error, such as [Failed to get canonical path of /cow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow), but I do not understand the nature of mounting here. My hard drive is `sda` and the usb where ubuntu installer is located is `sdb`. The `lsblk` command also shows `-sdb1` as a location with a type of part `/cdrom`.

I have included an image below which elucidates my configuration. Could someone please clarify how I have to mount grub given my configuration? My goal is to get Ubuntu to install and run with this 640x480 resolution so that I can update the drivers and all that once I have finally booted to the desktop. I have used the `nomodeset` option in the past, but it does not further the installation process. If anyone has any advice on how best to proceed from here to get to that goal, I would be exceptionally grateful.

[image: Screenshot of terminal showing output of 'lsblk' and 'df' commands]