# Ubuntu installation does not detect Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, windows-10

Trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 to laptop that contains Windows 10 OS. Installation does not detect Windows 10.

Disc is not dynamic and hibernate is disabled by executing `powercfg.exe /hibernate off`. BIOS mode is `Legacy`.

What else might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Run your grub update to scan and add other OS' on all attached drives to the menu boot menu.

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

**If Ubuntu isn't currently installed:**

Manually use create an partition for installing Ubuntu with a Partition Manager.  You can use gparted from the live disk.

Install Ubuntu.  The fresh install will find your other install Operating Systems and add them to the boot menu.

Some examples from ubuntuforums.org where this works:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2253963 
[Failed to get canonical path of /cow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow)

After the install you may have to run `os-prober`.

Comment: I have started console with CTRL+F1 and run sudo update-grub. Got "failed to get cannonical path of '/com'"

Comment: @vico Are you running this command from the Ubuntu installed on your computer or from a Live Boot disk?  ...and by the way, you can get to the a terminal window by hitting Alt-Ctl-T.

Comment: I run this command from Live Boot Disk during install procedure when I have menu "Preparing to install Ubuntu"

Comment: I interpreted your message to read that your install of was failing to include Windows 10 on the menu.  You would have to install Ubuntu first, then run the command in the answer.  Be sure to install on a separate partition so that your Windows installation won't be touched.  You can use gparted from the Live disk to create, resize, to make a partition for your Ubuntu Install.

Comment: I expect that Ubuntu install will detect windows 10 on system and will create  needed partitions for Ubuntu automatically.

Comment: @vico  I agree.  But there are occasions where the initial install scan doesn't catch it.  You might be able to eventually use various tools and diagnoses to make the install see it, or consider more expediently, performing a manual install of Ubuntu which gives you more options with the grub configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35022/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-vico).

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu, but after restart only Windows is loaded and no OS selection menu displayed

Comment: @vico http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35022/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-vico