# Unable to access Ubuntu after Windows install, reinstall grub fails

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

So after installing windows 10, it overrode grub and now Ubuntu is inaccessible. In the past, trying Ubuntu without installing it and reinstalling grub there worked, you know, this stuff:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair 

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Recently, Ubuntu says that it **cannot locate the package and that installing it is an unknown command** or something like that.

I would greatly appreciate anyone who points me in the right direction for getting grub to work or to get some other boot loader working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot the system with the ubuntu LiveCD.
2. open the Terminal and type `sudo fdisk -l`

   It will list number of partition. look which Device contain partition of the type  'Linux'
3. Copy the Device name containing the partition

   For example after typing `sudo fdisk -l`, It may list some device list like `/dev/sda1/`, `/dev/sda2/`, `/dev/sdb1/`. Look which device is of the Type Column for the name **Linux**

   Now if the partition name Linux is in device `/dev/sda3/` then you have to copy only **sda**
4. now type in the terminal `sudo grub-install /dev/XXX`

   where `xxx` is your  device name which contain linux partition ex `/dev/sda`
5. reboot your system

Comment: After attempting to install grub with sudo grub-install /dev/sda2, I got

"installing for i386-pc platform." THEN
 "Grub-install error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'." 

Not quite sure how to continue

Comment: @LiquidChicken may be you then try http://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow. If it solves, let me know