# Install Ubuntu: Wipe previous installs but do not touch my data partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, reinstall

I have a non-functional installation of 14.04, byproduct of a failed upgrade to 16.04 and an attempt at reinstalling 14.04. This is related to

[Install Ubuntu from ISO... cannot install grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845290/install-ubuntu-from-iso-cannot-install-grub)

[Broken 14.04 LTS while upgrading to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845301/broken-14-04-lts-while-upgrading-to-16-04)

So now I want to reinstall 14.04, wiping the previous installs. But I want my data partition sda4 to be untouched and accesible. Is that posible? Which option should be selected from the installation menú?

Comment: Do the manual partitioning and skip formatting of your data partition (sda4). BTW - I wouldn't go back to 14.04 -do the proper install of the latest Ubuntu instead, I'd say.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2057342

Comment: If you add a screenshot of your partition set up I can give you detailed instructions. Otherwise, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have a system partition that is separate from your data partition sda4.  I am not sure if sda4 is your /home partition.  These instructions assume that it is.  If it is not, you must add a /home partition in the same manner as the / partition is added in these instructions.

First, back up your data partition.  Then boot to the live USB

Choose the Something Else option in the installer.

On partition screen:

Double click system partition (sda1 or whatever)

Use as Ext4 journaling file system

Format the partition

Mount point /

Double click home partition (sda4 or whatever) << **this would be your data partition**

Use as Ext4 journaling file system

DO NOT Format the partition

Mount point /home

Double click swap partition (sda5 or whatever)

Just make sure it says use as swap area

At bottom of screen, device for boot loader installation, set to system disk (sda)