# failed to get canonical path of `/boot'

Tags: boot, grub2

Before this case, the console returned:

`/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'.`

then i solved this by following the steps on this page: [Failed to get canonical path of /cow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow).

but now when I run:

`sudo update-grub`

it returns:

`/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of '/boot'.`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96977/grub-wont-install