# Can't boot Lubuntu 18.04 on my asus t200ta

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, uefi

So I'm trying to install Lubuntu on my dad's asus T200TA (transformer) computer. At first, I had problems to make the computer recognize my boot (the boot worked well on other computers)
but I fixed it by :
- using UNetbootin to create my boot instead of Startup Disk creator
- copying bootia32.efi in /efi/boot/ with nautilus
Then, I could finally boot from my pendrive but, I'm now having the following problem : after I install lubuntu and restart my computer, it doesn't boot into lubuntu, it just goes back to the bios (I've willingly erased Windows 10 in the process of installing lubuntu), or it boots from my pendrive if i've plugged it, giving me the window where it asks me if I want to install or try lubuntu. So I've guessed it was a bootloader issue. So I did these things from my live usb lubuntu :
- I've tried fixing grub with boot repair but it didn't work
- I've tried fixing grub manually but I couldn't since it always returned "failed to get canonical path of '/cow'" (and couldn't fix it even with chroot, as explained here : [Failed to get canonical path of /cow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow))
- I've also tried to change of boot loader by installing rEFInd, making it by default boot loader, but it didn't work either.
- I've also tried to do all previous steps with a 32bits version of lubuntu, and had the exact same results
I admit I'm a bit desperate since I've spent almost two full days trying to install it. I'd be really grateful if someone could help me fixing this !! 
Thanks !!

Comment: Tough. You really did your homework. Care to look here for the resuce mode?: https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: I've just looked into it, but I can't access rescue mode as I can't select my Lubuntu installation from grub. I just can install it again, try it without installing etc ...
But thanks for the advice anyway :)