# Grub installation fails during xubuntu 20.04 install

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation, xubuntu

I am trying to install xubuntu 20.04 on a small Thinkpad x121e netbook with 8GB Men and a 250GB SSD. Until now I had Ubuntu 16.04 on it which installed without any problems.
The installation runs until it tries to install grub but end with the following error:

```
Unable to install grub on/dev/sda
Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed
This is a fatal error
```

No dual boot or any complex or exotic settings. I erased the drive and removed all previous partition with gparted.
I did a standard/default setting and also tried to tune the partitioning, using tips from some other posts about similar problems but without success until now.

Lots of error I found in other posts are often when users try to install in dual boot, which is not my case.
I really just want a standard installation...

Any hints? Or is the xubuntu installer buggy???

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried installing grub from a terminal having booted a live environment? The command would be sudo grub-install /dev/sda if your ssd is sda

Comment: Hi, yes I tried to and get the following error: 
> sudo grub-install /dev/sda "
Installing for i386-pc platform, 
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'"

Comment: This seems to be a highly regarded answer for this error https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow

Comment: @PonJar , Thanks for your responses. I finally set my computer to boot in legacy mode (non EFI) and could install xubuntu until end. Not sure what the problem was, but to me, it does look like the installer for grub in EFI mode is somehow buggy, after all the posts I have seen about problems with it and also because I really have a non exotic installation setup (one drive, no dual boot, etc...).