# grub2 - Failed to get canonical path of /cow

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I checked the link [Failed to get canonical path of /cow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow), but I'm still experiencing an error. I tried to install Ubuntu via usb on the pc and encountered a `failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow error`. I followed the link and when I enter the update-grub2 command, `error: cannot find a device for / (is/dev mounted?)` appears. Please help me

As a result, I want to move the current booting to the hard disk, which command should I enter?

I don't know where it went wrong.

Comment: You are running commands on live installer, not your install. /cow is copy on write or live installer which is not wrieable. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair            
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ What brand/model system?

Comment: @oldfred Why is it named "cow"?! At first glance, that doesn't seem to tell me anything meaningful about the directory. What is the `/cow` directory for?

Comment: /cow is Copy On Write. Or the live installer which you cannot update.