# Dual booting Windows server 2022 with Ubuntu server 2022 LTS Fail because of bad storage laout

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning

## Hardware & Background

- I had a [HP proliant ML102 v2](https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c04567801?jumpid=in_lit-psnow-red) (Windows Server 2012 R2) which was basically not being used for anything in the office , so I asked around and got the permission to repurpose it to be used for testing applications by dual booting windows server 2022 with Ubuntu 2022. I had to nuke the windows 2012 R2 as we could not get it to login ( we tried all our passwords).

## Problem

I installed Windows Server 2022 first as told by many forums made a partition for Ubuntu but could not make a ext4 partition from within Windows Server 2022 ( using default apps ). So I booted into the 32 GB pen drive with Ubuntu 2022 live server bootable in it ( made with rufus ).
[Image for rufus bootable wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f06Qr.png). I got to the ubuntu installer screen (subiquity) and chose the custom storage layout as I don't want to nuke my windows installation. I was presented with this screen.

```
 Storage configuration                                                                                                        [ Help ]
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
                 To continue you need to: Mount a filesystem at /
                                          Select a boot disk

                 FILE SYSTEM SUMMARY

                   No disks or partitions mounted.


                 AVAILABLE DEVICES

                   DEVICE                                             TYPE           SIZE
                 [ ST1000DM003-1ER162_W4Y509VL                        local disk   931.513G  ▸ ]
                   partition 1  existing, already formatted as ntfs, not mounted   100.000M  ▸
                   partition 2  existing, already formatted as ntfs, not mounted   686.761G  ▸
                   partition 3  existing, already formatted as ntfs, not mounted   524.000M  ▸
                   partition 4  existing, extended, unused                         244.139G  ▸

                 [ Create software RAID (md) ▸ ]
                 [ Create volume group (LVM) ▸ ]


                 USED DEVICES

                   No used devices
```

I selected partition 4 and formatted it with `ext4`.

```bash
┌──────────────── Editing partition 4 of ST1000DM003-1ER162_W4Y509VL ──────────────┐
│                            USED DEVICES                                          │
│                                                                                  │
│  Size (max 244.139G):  244.139G                                                  │
│                                                                                  │
│        No used devices                                                           │
│                                                                                  │
│                                                                                  │
│                  Format:  [ ext4              ▾ ]                                │
│                                                                                  │
│                                                                                  │
│                   Mount:  [ /               ▾ ]                                  │
│                                                                                  │
│                                                                                  │
│                             [ Save       ]                                       │
│                             [ Cancel     ]                                       │
│                                                                                  │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

- I had done this thrice , once I used sda5 as mount `/` , once I used sd4 ( which it didn't let me ) , then I used sda5 as mount `/` and sda 4 as `/boot`.
- Shortly after , it asks for my ubuntu password and name etc. But, stops in middle to interrupt setting my password while I am entering it. I initially thought they were because of incorrect mount settings as **I have installed ubuntu server 2022 before using the same bootable and on the same machine** but I used **full disk storage layout** instead of custom before.

## Things I have tried & Errors I got

- I also tried going into the shell parted the sda 5 as ext4 , which is the current (above ) screen state right now.
- I got ACPI errors like ( `journalctl -p 3` )

```bash
 ACPI: SPCR: Unexpected SPCR Access Width.  Defaulting to byte size
Aug 22 03:58:51 ubuntu-server kernel: DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x00000000000e8000-0x00000000000e8fff], contact BIOS vendo>
Aug 22 03:58:51 ubuntu-server kernel: [Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)
Aug 22 05:33:14 ubuntu-server kernel: EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
Aug 22 05:37:56 ubuntu-server kernel: ufs: ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write
```

AND

*while mounting sda5 in an attempt*

```
 unable to read superblock
Aug 22 05:37:56 ubuntu-server kernel: ufs: ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write
```

and Also got an `no NUMA configuration error` :

- At this point , I had done almost everything to fix it. One Askubuntu thread suggested to change grub file but then I could not update-grub because of [/cow error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow) . Then I searched for the answer and I got a hotfix to use  `sudo touch /cow` which worked but now I see :

```bash
/sda1 Windows Recovery Environment 
/sda2 Windows Recovery Environment
/sda3 Windows Recovery Environment
```

> I will update this thread with more errors and troubleshoots that I continue doing, but in the meantime if anyone can help me out , or if you need any more clarification please do let me know.

Edit :  Here is the error screen I get , It seems like it takes about 80 seconds irrespective of what I enter in the profile setting step to show me this error screen :

```
An error occurred during installation                                                                                        [ Help ]
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
                 ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
                 │subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config                                                                                           │
                 │subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config                                                                                       │
                 │subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config                                                                                           │
                 │subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config                                                                                        │
                 │subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config                                                                                         │
                 │subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config                                                                                         │
                 │subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config                                                                                          │
                 │subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config                                                                                            │
                 │subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config                                                                                            │
                 │configuring apt                                                                                                                    │
                 │  curtin command in-target                                                                                                         │
                 │installing system                                                                                                                  │
                 │  executing curtin install initial step                                                                                            │
                 │  executing curtin install partitioning step                                                                                       │
                 │    curtin command install                                                                                                         │
                 │      configuring storage                                                                                                          │
                 │        running 'curtin bl                                                                                                         │
                 │          curtin command b   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐                            │
                 │            removing previ   │                                                                        │                            │
                 │            configuring di   │  Sorry, there was a problem completing the installation.               │                            │
                 │          configuring part   │                                                                        │                            │
                 │          configuring part   │                       [ View full report      ]                        │                            │
                 │          configuring part   │                                                                        │                            │
                 │          configuring part   │  If you want to help improve the installer, you can send an error      │                            │
                 │          configuring form   │  report.                                                               │                            │
                 │                             │                                                                        │                            │
                 │                             │                       [ Send to Canonical     ]                        │                            │
                 │                             │                                                                        │                            │
                 │                             │  Do you want to try starting the installation again?                   │                            │
                 │                             │                                                                        │                            │
                 │                             │                       [ Restart the installer ]                        │                            │
                 │                             │                                                                        │                            │
                 │                             │                       [ Close report          ]                        │                            │
                 │                             │                                                                        │                            │
                 │                             └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘                            │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 │                                                                                                                                   │
                 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

                                                                         [ View full log     ]
                                                                         [ View error report ]
                                                                         [ Reboot Now        ]
```