# How to change Monitor of ubuntu box Also 'Out of Frequency ' Error due to monitor change

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, monitor

I have find very odd and crude solution to this entire episode. It is as follows

1. Start installing ubuntu as usual.
2. Switch off the monitor
3. Wait for some time (1-2 minutes)  till the HDD  access stops .
4. At this point ubuntu needs some input from the user
5. Now Switch on the monitor and high chances are that you will see ubuntu normally no out of frequency issues.

Now onwards there will not be any 'out of frequency' issue.

I have successfully installed ubuntu with this workaround.

It is quite  useful for newbies in ubuntu. As all other ways are somewhat complex to do especially for a newbie.

Thank you all especially  bain  who guide me thru the maze.

===================================================================================================**The issue i was facing few months ago**=======================

I was trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on p4 . but it was not getting installed due to some issues which i do not understand. 
 it used to give ' Frequency out of range ' message and the monitor used to go into 'stand by mode' . I could never install ubuntu with the old CRT monitor. So i borrowed a latest LCD monitor and was able to install ubuntu successfully. Now  i want to use my old  monitor so i changed the monitor back to CRT but it again start giving the same error. 
Experts are requested to guide me about how to change the monitor of the successfully installed Ubuntu. The details are as follows.

My hardware :=
P4 3.06 MHz / 2 GB ram / 10 Gb hdd totally dedicated to Ubuntu / 2gb swap space. 
MoBo Mercury P4 266aNDMx 865 Equivalent.
Monitor LG CRT Studioworks 500G (8 Years old ) with max resolution of 1024 X 768.
The entire hardware works perfectly under XP.

Error Message :-
Out of frequency 
  HF  68.7 KHz
  VF  85.0

HF  30 - 54 kHz
VF   50 - 120 Hz

The monitor starts a 15 sec countdown with 'Frequency out or range box'

before entering power saving mode.

On the  LCD monitor I have changed following settings within  Ubuntu before switching over to CRT monitor.

1. grub    GRUB_GRXMODE changed twice once for 800X600 as well as  for 1024X768 followed by sudo  ubdate-grub each time.
2. monitor resolution correspondingly  was adjusted in ubuntu for 800X600 as well as 1024X768.

The ' Out of frequency ' may be happening due to some different reason. Experts comment.

Regards
kanade

XRandr output for LCD is

```
1360x768 60.0* 
1024x768 75.0 60.0 70.0 
800x600 75.0 60.0 72.0 56.0 
640x480 75.0 60.0 73.0 
512x384 75.0 70.0 60.0 
400x300 75.0 72.0 60.0 56.0 
320x240 75.0 73.0 60.0
```

[Xorg log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7516121/)

Decoded EDID from Xorg log:

```
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "505E"
    ModelName "505E"
    VendorName "GSM"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 3 of 2005
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Analog Display
    DisplaySize 280 210
    Gamma 2.76
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-54
    VertRefresh 50-120
    # Maximum pixel clock is 70MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 640x480, 85Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 800x600, 85Hz
    Modeline    "Mode 0" -hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" +hsync +vsync 
EndSection
```

According to [this page](http://www.comx-computers.co.za/download/lg-electronics/LG505E.php) the monitor specs are:

```
Max Resolution : Manual : 1024 x 768 / 65 Hz
Recommended Resolution : 800 x 600 / 85 Hz
H-Scanning Frequency : 30 ~ 54 kHz
V-Scanning Frequency : 50 ~ 120 Hz
Pixel Frequency : 65 MHz
```

Xorg detects pixel clock as 75 Mhz. I think this monitor is capable of displaying an interlaced signal upto 120 Mhz which is why the frequency calculation is wrong.

Hi

I did not tell you earlier that the installation procedure had worked perfectly with same CRT monitor for buntu 7.04 but ironically the issue has started for newer versions!

I have tried totally 4 versions of Ubuntu 7.04, 11.10, 12.10, 14.04LTA.

Any way keep reading

I tried to generate Xorg.conf file on CRT on a terminal tty1, and the server has crashed here is the url of the log file      http://paste.ubuntu.com/7521633/  it may be of some help.

Xorg has stopped unexpectedly

Also read this lengthy message   may be of any use.

" Your system is proving 3D via software rendering rather than hardware rendering this is a compatibility mode which should display 3D graphics properly but the performance may be very poor. If the problem you are reporting is related to graphics performance your real question may be why X did not use hardware acceleration for your system"

Comment: Have you seen [frequency out of range - please change display mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153040/frequency-out-of-range-please-change-display-mode)?

Comment: What is the output of `xrandr`?

Comment: Does this happen if you boot 14.04 with the CRT monitor already plugged in? Do you have anything in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`?

Comment: Also see [How to add display resolution fo an LCD in Ubuntu 12.04? xrandr problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138408/how-to-add-display-resolution-fo-an-lcd-in-ubuntu-12-04-xrandr-problem)

Comment: It does happen when CRT is attached and i have opened /etc/X11/xorg.conf it is empty

Comment: XRandr output for LCD is                                         1360x768       60.0* 
   1024x768       75.0     60.0     70.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.0     72.0     56.0  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     73.0  
   512x384        75.0     70.0     60.0  
   400x300        75.0     72.0     60.0     56.0  
   320x240        75.0     73.0     60.0

Comment: Hello bain i have installed ubuntu finally with a workaround  kindly go through my post at the beginning. thank you for the help. I will try solutions suggested by you in future.

Answer (score 1):

> Out of frequency HF 68.7 KHz
>   HF 30 - 54 kHz

Looks like the clock frequency is too high, possibly because it is configured for your new monitor. Try:

```
$ cvt 1024 768
# 1024x768 59.92 Hz (CVT 0.79M3) hsync: 47.82 kHz; pclk: 63.50 MHz
Modeline "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1024x768_60.00"
$ xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1024x768_60.00"
```

Comment: It had happened even before i had used LCD monitor. should i try for the lowest end of the resolution in grub ??

Comment: If your monitor is capable of 1024x768 then you should be able to use that resolution. For some reason it appears the video card is outputting the video at a frequency the montior does not support (not the resolution, but the signal frequency). The commands here will manually add a 1024x768 resolution frequency that should be compatible with your monitor.

Comment: This should be automatic, I do not know why it does not work for you, perhaps you could boot with the CRT monitor attached, then `ssh` in remotely and check the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Comment: Hello bain Thank you for your guidance i have got the log file with me with CRT monitor. I don't understand anything from it so you have to read it and guide me further it is quite big 50k + so how to send that to you ???

Comment: Paste it to pastebin then edit your question and add the link. Did you try adding the new mode with `xrandr`?

Comment: Hello bain i have added the log to pastebin http://paste.ubuntu.com/7516121/    Go thru it and give your diagnosis. i did not add the new mode.

Comment: It looks like that log is for your new monitor? Can you boot with your CRT monitor connected and then log in remotely with `ssh` and copy `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: Another thing to try: connect old monitor, hold shift when booting up to start grub, edit boot parameters and replace `splash quiet` with `text`, login on a virtual terminal, do `X -configure`

Comment: (the problem could be that you have S3 Savage graphics, according to [`man savage`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man4/savage.4.html) it is possible for this driver to use too fast a frequency, which requires a manual override to fix - another option would be to use a different graphics card)

Comment: Hello bain The logs are for CRT monitor only . can you suggest any way to change frequency of graphics manually / any url or a book

Comment: Plug in your LCD monitor, change resolution and refresh rate with `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 800x600 --rate 60` then connect the CRT monitor (do not reboot, xrandr is not persistent), it should work?

Comment: hi bain  Thank you for your reply. i have already done that. with working ubuntu on LCD i had lowered resolution and attached CRT. It works smoothly. i want to use CRT right from booting.

Comment: Oh good, in that case follow [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent#69501) to make it permanent: in your `mycustomloginvideo.sh` do `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 800x600 --rate 60`

Comment: Hello bain i have installed ubuntu finally with a workaround kindly go through my post at the beginning. thank you for the help. I will try solutions suggested by you in future.

Comment: The log you posted shows a crash in the S3 driver which you could report to Xorg at https://bugs.freedesktop.org/